# Cant get firebase to stop overriding old pictures when I upload them in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase

Firebase overirdes my old pictures each time I upload the new picture, I want it to save my old pictures

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Firebase Storage</title>  
</head>
<body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
<button type="submit" onclick="window.open('#blah')">Download!</button>

    </form>    

    <a download="new-image.png" id="download">Download</a>







<label>Image File:</label>
<br/>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    <button onclick="myFunctiondown()">Click me</button>
    <button onclick="myFunctionleft()">Click me</button>
    <button onclick="myFunctionleft2()">Click me</button>
    <button onclick="myFunctiontext()">Click me</button>


    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />

<h1>Example of using <code>&lt;canvas&gt;</code></h1>

<p>This example shows how a photo is loaded in a <code>&lt;canvas&gt;</code> tag and then flipped.</p>

<p>Click on the photo to flip (provided, of course, that your browser supports <code>&lt;canvas&gt;</code>)</p>

<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px red solid;"></canvas>

<a download="new-image.png" id="download">Download</a>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    

 <script src="add-download-btn.js"></script>   

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

  <h1>Firebase Storage</h1>  

  <input type="file" id="fileButton">

  <div id="image" style=""></div>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase.js"></script>

    <style>

        img {


            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
        }









    #image{
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
}


        #dwnld{
    float:left;
}

.button {
    appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none; font: menu; color: ButtonText;
    display: inline-block; padding: 2px 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
}    




    .btn {

  padding: 5px 10px;

  font-size: 16px;

  border-radius: 3px;

  border: solid 1px #C0392B;

  background-color: #E74C3C;

  text-decoration: none;

  color: white;

}



.btn:hover {

  opacity: .9;

}



.btn:active {

  opacity: 1;

}



             canvas {
    height: 50vh;    

    }  



    </style>

    <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAMEuYur7_ExqF92Os02kRlZbSXIHdfDjE",
    authDomain: "danniauth.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://danniauth.firebaseio.com",

    projectId: "danniauth",
    storageBucket: "danniauth.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "279422179745"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

  <script>

//$(document).ready(function () {
  //          $("#blah").click(function () {
//                $("img").animate({

  //                  height: '+=5px',
//                    width: '+=5px'
  //              });

//            var button = document.getElementById('download');
//  button.setAttribute( 'href', can.toDataURL('image/png', 1) );



//            });
    //    });




   var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);


var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');




var img = new Image();


function handleImage(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {

    img.onload = function() {
      can.width = img.width;
      can.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
      ctx.save();
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}




function myFunction() {
  console.log('here');
   can.width = img.width;
      can.height = img.height;

    ctx.translate(img.width - 500, img.height - 505);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
  ctx.translate(-(img.width - 500), -(img.height - 505));
    ctx.drawImage(img, 60, 60, img.width, img.height);

  var button = document.getElementById('download');
  button.setAttribute( 'href', can.toDataURL('image/png', 1) );

};    



function myFunctiondown() {
  console.log('here');
   can.width = img.width;
      can.height = img.height;

    ctx.translate(img.width - 1, img.height - 1);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
//  ctx.translate(-(img.width - 500), -(img.height - 505));
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

  var button = document.getElementById('download');
  button.setAttribute( 'href', can.toDataURL('image/png', 1) );

};        



function myFunctionleft() {
  console.log('here');
   can.width = img.width;
      can.height = img.height;

    ctx.translate(img.width - 500, img.height - 500);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI/360);
  ctx.translate(-(img.width - 500), -(img.height - 505));
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

  var button = document.getElementById('download');
  button.setAttribute( 'href', can.toDataURL('image/png', 1) );

};    




        function myFunctionleft2() {
  console.log('here');
   can.width = img.width;
      can.height = img.height;

    ctx.translate(img.width - 500, img.height - 500);
  ctx.rotate(270 * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.translate(-(img.width - 500), -(img.height - 505));
    ctx.drawImage(img, 164, 164, img.width, img.height);

  var button = document.getElementById('download');
  button.setAttribute( 'href', can.toDataURL('image/png', 1) );

};        












//////////////////////////////      




  //    function readURL(input) {

//  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
//    var reader = new FileReader();

//    reader.onload = function(e) {
//      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
 //   }

 //   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
//  }
//}

//$("#imgInp").change(function() {
//  readURL(this);
//});     


//$('#download').attr('scr', e.target.result())       








    /*
     *
     * Create a variable to reference the upload button.
     *
     */
    var fileButton = $('#fileButton' );

    /*
     *
     * Add a change event listener the upload button. 
     *
     */
    fileButton.change(function(event){

      //      ImageTools.resize(this.files[0], {
    //    width: 320, // maximum width
  //      height: 240 // maximum height
//    }, function(blob, didItResize) {
        // didItResize will be true if it managed to resize it, otherwise false (and will return the original file as 'blob')
   //     document.getElementById('image').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // you can also now upload this blob using an XHR.
 //   });


      /*
       * Create a variable and get the relevant file objec
       */





        var file = event.target.files[0];

      /* 
       * Create a Firebase reference for a new image.
                                       *user/number.jpg
       */  //+ new Date().getTime() + file.name).put(file);

      var ref = firebase.storage().ref('/images/testing.jpg');
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("user");
      var userRef = storageRef.child(user.uid);    


        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if( user )
        {
          $('.unauthed').hide();
          $('.authed').show();
            console.log(user.uid);
        }
        else
        {

        }
      });

      /*
       * Upload the file using the Firebase reference. 
       */
        userRef.put(file);
        ref.put(file);

      /*
       * Retrieve the full URL of the uploaded file and place it into an IMG tag 
       * in the DIV with the id of IMAGE.
       *$('#image').width(100);
       */

          ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){

          $('#image').html('<img src="'+url+'">');

      });      

    });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There was an alert asking you to add more details when you first tried to post the question, /////////// ... is not what was expected.

Comment: Please try improving your question. What did you try so far? Was there any errors? And so on.

Comment: i tried adding something like this  var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + new Date().getTime() + file.name).put(file, metadata);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you upload files with:

```
userRef.put(file);
ref.put(file);
```

Every time you run this code, it adds the data to the exact same location, overwriting whatever you previously wrote at that location.

To store multiple files, you'll need to create a new unique `StorageReference` each time you want to upload a file. A simple way to do that would be to use the timestamp in the file name:

```
userRef.child(Date.now()).put(file);
```

This means that each file is stored in a "folder" for the user, and then with the current timestamp under there.

Comment: ok i got it working with var userRef = storageRef.child(user.uid + Date.now());